# PowerShell online get error by correlation id not working

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, error, online

Have script

```
$adminUPN="myname@fmyname.onmicrosoft.com"
$orgName="myname"
$userCredential = Get-Credential -UserName $adminUPN -Message "Type the password."
Connect-SPOService -Url https://$orgName-admin.sharepoint.com -Credential $userCredential
$endTimeinUTC = Get-SPOTenantLogLastAvailableTimeInUtc
$startTimeinUTC = $endTimeinUTC.AddDays -14
$tenantlogs = Get-SPOTenantLogEntry -StartTimeinUtc $startTimeinUTC -EndTimeinUTC $endTimeinUTC -CorrelationId e2c3b19d-a0ff-3000-9581-1c7740558593
```

Make it using https://technet.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/fp161369.aspx

But got error "Method invocation failed because [System.Management.Automation.PSMethod] does not contain a method named 'op_Subtraction'."

Any ideas? Im connecting to sharepoint online

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the subtraction at start time is not working.please replace this line

```
$startTimeinUTC = $endTimeinUTC.AddDays -14
```

With this line

```
$startTimeinUTC = $endTimeinUTC.AddDays (-14)
```

Comment: Then i got this error: `At C:\uninstall.ps1:6 char:41
+ $startTimeinUTC = $endTimeinUTC.AddDays (-14)
+                                         ~
Unexpected token '(' in expression or statement.
    + CategoryInfo          : ParserError: (:) [], ParseException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnexpectedToken` this is why I write -14 not (-14)

Comment: Adddays is method so you have to put in (), are you getting any value for $endtimeinutc?